# Change root context for a servlet in an IntelliJ IDEA project

Tags: tomcat, servlets, intellij-idea

I have created two servlets that run when I use their url-pattern that is defined in my web.xml file.

For example, to run the first one I type  the following in my browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/XmlServletPath
```

I want to find a way to run these servlets from a different root context, for example:

```
http://localhost:8080/SimpleServletProject/XmlServletPath
```

When I try the above URL now I am getting the following error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /SimpleServletProject/XmlServletPath

type Status report
message /SimpleServletProject/XmlServletPath
description The requested resource is not available.
```

PS: I am using Tomcat 7.0.35.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Application context** can be specified in the **Deployment** tab of the Tomcat Run/Debug configuration:

[image: context]

Comment: I did that and now nothing is working any more.Nothing at all.Neither my index.jsp page nor my servlets.

Comment: Please zip and share your sample project to reproduce. It definitely works for me.

Comment: Ok, here it goes : https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxjdiwIZVU9OZEs0OHlKbVFScWc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You are deploying under `/SimpleServerProject`, but the URL that opens in the browser is `http://localhost:8080/SimpleServletProject`. Can you see the difference between **Servlet** and **Server** in the URLs? Also, [this mapping](http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/7003/20130320030249.png) should be set to `/`.

Comment: Ok I solved it. The key is that startup page must be the same as Application Context.Thank you for your help!