# Dont work RESTEasy in jax-rs

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs

The following RESTFull service does not work
pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>uz.salvadore.app</groupId>
<artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>My First Application</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>JBoss repository</id>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.21</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

web.xml

```
 <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>uz.salvadore.app.MessageApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<!-- this need same with resteasy servlet url-pattern -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>
```

MessageRestService.java

```
 package uz.salvadore.rest;

 import javax.ws.rs.GET;
 import javax.ws.rs.Path;
 import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
 import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
 import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

 @Path("/message")
 @Produces("text/plain")
 public class MessageRestService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response printMessage(@PathParam("param") String msg) {
        return Response.status(200).entity("Hello " + msg).build();
    }

 }
```

MessageApplication.java

```
 package uz.salvadore.app;

 import uz.salvadore.rest.MessageRestService;

 import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
 import java.util.HashSet;
 import java.util.Set;

 public class MessageApplication extends Application {

    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

    public MessageApplication() {
        singletons.add(new MessageRestService());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }

 }
```

I use tomcat 7.0.69
My error http://localhost:9999/RESTEasy/rest/message/hello
HTTP Status 404 The requested resource is not available.

Comment: Are you sure that Your application deployed correctly? Also check Tomcat configuration files (context.xml ?), make sure that RESTEasy is correct context path.

Comment: I use the Intellij IDE and I did not configure nothing, i create package main and put in 2 folders java and webapp. In webapp folder contains folder WEB-INF->web.xml, and the folder java my project package (uz.salvadore.app->MessageApplication and uz.salvadore.rest->MessageRestService). Tomcat running successfully and opened the localhost in the browser, but when i write my path showing the error 404

Comment: What is the URL of tomcat when it opens in browser after starting?

Comment: http://localhost:9999

Comment: Did You try 'http://localhost:9999/rest/message/hello' ? Also check this post that shows how to change context path for Tomcat in Idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508967/change-root-context-for-a-servlet-in-an-intellij-idea-12-project