# URL localhost:8080/<project_name>/Servlet don't works

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, localhost, servlet-3.0

I'm trying to run my simple servlet "Hello".
I have installed tomcat 9.0.6
Than i create a new JavaEE web project in Idea (called test)... after i create new package in src (called servlet), after new servlet file "myServlet".
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we5ZJ.png)
Here is code:

```
public class myServlet extends HttpServlet {
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.println("<html><body>");

    out.println("<h2>Hello my first Servlet</h2>");
    out.println("<br/>");
    out.println("Time on the server is: " + new java.util.Date());

    out.println("</body></html>");
}


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

Than i open web.xml and add next lines for servlet and servlet-mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
     version="4.0">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.myServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

After successfully running tomcat ("Artifact is deployed successfully") i try to visit url: http://localhost:8080/test/myServlet   
 Result was page 404... 
But if i change url to: http://localhost:8080/myServlet 
 result was correct.
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMAJw.png)

What's wrong with url: http://localhost:8080/test/myServlet ???
Need some libraries or what ??? 
Where is my mistake ???

Also i try with @WebServlet("/myServlet") annotation without servlet and servlet-mapping lines in web.xml  - result the same.

Comment: is test is the name of your application

Comment: Where i can look it ??

Comment: suggesting to take a look at spring-boot https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/

Comment: I don't think there's a mistake, IntelliJ will by default deploy your application to the root context. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508967/change-root-context-for-a-servlet-in-an-intellij-idea-12-project

Comment: Thanks, now i got what is was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the context path in context.xml - please see this link
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context

Comment: Thanks, now i can change context path.